# How do you set up a websocket to an external API?

Tags: javascript, express, websocket

I have a route set up that gets the weather for a city from the [openweathermap API](https://openweathermap.org/api)

index.js file

```
var express  = require("express"),
    router   = express.Router();
var weather = require("openweather-apis");

router.get("/weather", function(req, res){
  weather.setCity('Miami');
  weather.setAPPID(appID);
  weather.getAllWeather(function(err, allWeather){
    res.json({allWeather: allWeather});
  });
});
```

And I want to set up a websocket to this route, such that each time there is a change I get an update that I can display to users. I have tried this:

index.ejs file

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/socket.io-client@2/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000/weather');
  socket.on('connect', function(){});
  socket.on('event', function(data){
   // do something
  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){});
</script>
```

But I keep getting errors. If anyone can give me an idea of what I'm doing wrong, please help!

I get the following error:

```
index.js:83 GET http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mzd4Dpj 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: Please post the error details.

Comment: Updated answer with error!

Comment: websockets provide routes? I think the first code shown is an express.js which provides a Webserver and the second is Socket.io which depends an a WebSOCKETServer. This wont work together

Comment: @Mandalina - Did you started the server. i:e `node server.js (or your backend file)`?

Comment: @random ya I have it started, and thats the error I get

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't per se. The client connects to a websocket. The websocket doesn't connect to anything, it is what the client connects to. (A websocket client can't connect to a regular HTTP endpoint).

If you want to broadcast data over a websocket when the response to a traditional HTTP web service changes, then you would need to poll the web service's URL (e.g. with `setInterval`) and then emit the data over the websocket when you get new data in the response.

`http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mzd4Dpj` is giving you a `404` error because you haven't provided a websocket on the server for the client to connect to. The [getting started documentation](https://socket.io/get-started/chat/) will walk you through setting up the server-side half of Socket.io. You can't use the client-side half of it without the server to connect to.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much for responding! How do I set up polling over the websocket?

Comment: @Mandalina — Worry about setting up the server-side part of the websocket first. The documentation I pointed to has a section on Broadcasting. Use that to send data over the socket.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll set that up now